# Is there a way to modify the mouse with ocgx2?

Tags: ocg, ocgx2

I wrote a transparency with Beamer containing a timed `itemize list` *(overlay)* and an `OCG layer`.
When the mouse is not above the OCG link called "circle", it has the following form: [image: sur la page]

When the mouse is above the OCG link called "circle", it has the following shape:

[image: sur le lien]

The problem is that the shape of the mouse in both cases is really very close and their colors are so identical that in class I often confuse them.
Instead of clicking on the mouse when it is above the "circle" link, I click right next to it. This makes the hidden text visible in the bulleted list prematurely.
Is there a way to colorize the mouse of the color of the link it flies over?
And if not, leave his classic appearance?

the code is this:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.3\textwidth}
Bla bla bla\dots
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item visible text
\item first hidden text
\item second hidden text
\end{itemize}
\switchocg{cercle}{\textcolor{blue}{circle}}

\column{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ocg={name=cercle,ref=cercle,status=invisible}]
\draw[red,very thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to see if you can change the behavior of your cursor (its appearance) *within the pdf reader*, and that this behaviour can't be determined by the `pdf`: the `pdf` only tells the viewer "this is a clickable area", but do not indicate which shape should the cursor take. I might be wrong, though, but couldn't find anything related to your question in `ocgx` or `ocgx2` manuals.

Comment: @Clément  The appearance of the mouse  can be modified via javascript.  Adobe has developed javascript for acrobat as shown here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

Not being able to program in javascript, nor in javascript for acrobat, I don't know how to do that. Nevertheless, it is possible, but how? https://gehrcke.de/2010/11/javascript-in-pdf-using-latex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizing the mouse pointer does not seem possible, even by JavaScript.

For obtaining a stronger visual feedback of the current mouse position, a **colour change** of the link text ("circle") could be implemented, which occurs on mouse-over and mouse-out events.

[image]

For this, the example uses the optional `<trigger>` argument of the `\switchocg` command, set to `onmouseall`. It allows configuring all possible mouse events. Though *not* depending on JavaScript, it does only work in Acrobat Reader (and other non-free PDF viewers).

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.3\textwidth}
Bla bla bla\dots
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item visible text
\item first hidden text
\item second hidden text
\end{itemize}

%the PDF-layer switching link to be highlighted on mouse-over
\makebox[0pt][l]{\switchocg[onmouseall]{
  circle-orange, % onmousenter: toggle link colour 
  circle-orange, % onmouseexit: toggle link colour
  ,              % onmousedown: -
  cercle         % onmouseup:   toggle visibility of layer with red circle
}{\textcolor{blue}{circle}}}%
\begin{ocg}{circle-orange}{circle-orange}{off}\textcolor{orange}{circle}\end{ocg}

% PDF layer with TikZ graphic
\column{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ocg={name=cercle,ref=cercle,status=invisible}]
\draw[red,very thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```